# retain viewcontroller - message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to use the UIWebViewDelegate, however, when I set delegate to it's self, I get a 'message sent to deallocated instance' error.

Actual error: "2014-04-07 22:12:05.402 `AppName[746:60b] -[WebViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa47ae00"`

I presume this is because the WebViewController instance has not been retained?

Could anyone point me in the right direction for this please?

My structure is:
RootViewController > WebViewController (delegate) > WebView

```
// root.h
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) WebViewController * webViewController;
@end

// root.m

#import "RootViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    _webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

    [self.view addSubview:_webViewController.view];

}

@end

// .h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property(strong) UIWebView *webView;
@end

// .m

#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface WebViewController ()
@end

@implementation WebViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    _webView.delegate = self;
    NSString *url = @"http://google.com/";
    NSURL *nsurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [_webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];
}

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"ui web view started load");
}
```

Comment: `webViewController` is being retained by the ivar pointer so that doesn't seem to be it. I don't have an answer at a glance but I do have a comment which is that you forgot to add `nonatomic` to the webView property. Almost certainly unintended.

Comment: Can you paste in the actual message with its details in case there's something you're not describing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not set the root view controller like so:

```
    self.window.rootViewController = rootController;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your code out of `loadView` into `viewDidLoad`, and remove your calls to `loadView`. I believe `loadView` is called automatically when the view controller is instantiated and shown, so calling it again might cause you to instantiate your webview twice.

From the docs:

> You should never call this method directly. The view controller calls
>   this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil.
>   This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view
>   property.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but with the changes the same error occurs.
i've updated the question with your suggested update.